# Microsoft Office Word add-in paste functionality - C#

Tags: c#, ms-word, ms-office, add-on

I have a simple word add-on which I use to paste a sequence of strings into different places of a Microsoft Word document.

Currently I am using these lines of code, to get the information about the position:

```
 int PageNumber = range.get_Information(WdInformation.wdActiveEndPageNumber);
 int ColumnNumber = range.get_Information(WdInformation.wdFirstCharacterColumnNumber);
 int LineNumber = range.get_Information(WdInformation.wdFirstCharacterLineNumber);
```

I need a way to track their place dynamically. Let’s say if user paste a name somewhere, and then our user decides to change the contents of document before this pasted name.

Do I need to parse the entire document to find my pasted string?

What if it’s a common string value like "Hello"? Can I hide or attach something to my pasted string dynamically? Like a pointer to specific string in document?

I appreciate any help or idea, thanks.

Comment: Have you looked at bookmarks? They provide another way of referring to your text.

Comment: Thanks Lan, I used the bookmarks and it works great. Do you think if there is a way to hide these bookmarks from user?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the comments above it sounds like bookmarks provide what you need. Bookmarks can be hidden - to do that (IIRC) you need to give them a name that begins with an underscore. If you want to iterate over your hidden bookmarks later on then you need to set

```
Bookmarks.ShowHidden = true
```

beforehand.